# Making Friend Connections For Test Users

Tags: facebook, testing

Using the Roles dashboard, I can create Facebook test user accounts but when trying to make them friends with each other via ticking appropriate accounts and then the 'make friends' button seems to do absolutely nothing.

I have then tried to make these accounts friends via the api call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{test user id 1}/friends/{test user id 2}?method=post&access_token={test user 1 access token}`

This results in an OAuth Exception being returned:

`{"error":{"message":"Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}`

This feature has worked previously for me (clicking the make friends button). Has anyone got any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug, you can now go in via the modify roles menu in the application and select users to 'make friends'. This functionality is still pretty buggy but it does work eventually.

Comment: I am surprised that Facebook still has such a bug existing there.

Comment: 2020 and it is still buggy :(. Can't make to test users to be friends using the FB Roles Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

There is ui for it now which is helpful, the only bummer is that I also get the same OAuth exception as the original poster. It'd be nice to be able to do this with an API.

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

**Now Facebook Resolve this from their End. Any developer can manually create a friend list for test user from developer console.**

**Follow the Below Steps:**

**Step-1:** Login in Your developer console and click on you app project.

**Click on Link to login**: [Facebook Developer Account Link](https://developers.facebook.com/products/audience-network/)

**Step-2:** Inside their you can see **Roles** click on their and then click on **Test Users**

See Below attached Images:
[image]

**Step-3:** Now click on Add to create number of test user. One Popup is display which you can see in below images. At their you have to mention test user permission which you want to perform.

For example,  If you want to fetch list of test user friends then you need **user_friends** permission.

To get more link about Facebook permission/scope visit [Facebook Permission Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference)
[image]

**Step-4:** Here in below image you can see list of test user which you created using step-3. Now you can click on **Edit** to add those other test user as friend of one another. for that you to click in **Manage this test user friends**  and add other test user name in popup dialog. [image]

Similarly you can also assign permission or remove test user once as per your requirement.   This is it.